# Content hides under header container with slideshow background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm really new in front-end and faced a problem. I wanted to make navigation container with logo and menu, which has a background of slideshow. I made that, it works. But as I see, my next content appears straight off navigation container, not after slideshow container. I tried to put margin-top, and pull down the text text text content, but in responsive design, for example mobile phone, it appears far away down the slideshow, on computer - on the slideshow and so on, so margin-top is not the solution I think. It seems, that text content does not see, where slideshow container ends.

I'm adding a picture to illustrate this problem (also added another photo after navigation to show, that it appears straight off the navigation container).

Do you have any ideas, how to fix that?

[image]

```js
$(function() {
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<7)
    {
        $('li').has('ul').mouseover(function(){
            $(this).children('ul').css('visibility','visible');
        }).mouseout(function(){
            $(this).children('ul').css('visibility','hidden');
        })
    }
});

/* MOBILE RESPONSIVE */

$('#menu-wrap').prepend('<div id="menu-trigger">Menu</div>');
$("menu-trigger").on("click", function(){
    $("#menu").slideToggle();
});

/* IPAD RESPONSIVE */

var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
if (isiPad) $('#menu ul').addClass('no-transition');
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

img, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}

/* HEADER START */                  /* logo and menu */

.foreground-container {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    /*top: 0;*/
    z-index: 99;
}

#logo-bg {
    background-color: rgba(000,000,000,.7);
    margin-top: 50px;
}

/* DROPDOWN MENU START */

.menu-right {                                   /* floats menu to right */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#menu, #menu ul {
    /*margin-top: auto;*/
    /*margin: 130px 0 0 0;*/
    /*margin-right: -30px;*/
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#menu {
    max-width: 100%;        /*662*/
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444), to(#111));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -o-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #777, 0 1px 0 #666 inset;
}

#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu: after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu {
    zoom: 1;
}

#menu li {
    display: inline-flex;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;       /* Išskyrus kontaktai iš dešinės! */
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    -o-box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
}

#menu li:last-child {
    border-right: 0px solid #222 !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 0 0 #444 !important;
}

#menu a {
    display: flex;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    color: #999;
    /*text-transform: uppercase;*/
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover {
    color: #fafafa;         /* IE6 only*/
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0;             /* IE6 only*/
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #444;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444), to(#111));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(225,225,225,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(225,225,225,.3);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(225,225,225,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(225,225,225,.3);
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    _margin: 0;             /* IE6 only*/
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    -o-box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

#menu ul li {
    /* float: none; */
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    _line-height: 0;        /* IE6 only */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
}

#menu ul li:last-child {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#menu ul a {
    padding: 10px;
    /* max-width: 130px; */           /* išsiskleidžiančios lentelės plotis */
    _height: 10px;          /* IE6 only */
    display: block;
            /* ? */
    /* float: none; */
    text-align: center;
}

#menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #0186ba;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#04acec, #0186ba);
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -o-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;                 /* trikampiukas nuo kairio krašto */
    top: -6px;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #444;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid #3b3b3b;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #04acec;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #0299d3;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

#menu ul li:last-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

/* DROPDOWN MENU END */

/* BACKGROUND MENU START */

.background-container {                           /* slider */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    /* background-size: cover; */
}

.slideshow-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.fadein img {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;       /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 40s;
    -o-animation-name: fade;            /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    -o-animation-duration: 40s;
    -moz-animation-name: fade;          /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    -moz-animation-duration: 40s;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 40s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    position: absolute;                 /* fixed */
}

.fadein img:nth-child(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.fadein img:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: 8s; }
.fadein img:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: 16s; }
.fadein img:nth-child(4) { animation-delay: 24s; }
.fadein img:nth-child(5) { animation-delay: 32s; }

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    5% {opacity: 1;}
    22.5% {opacity: 1;}
    27.5% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    5% {opacity: 1;}
    22.5% {opacity: 1;}
    27.5% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

/* BACKGROUND MENU END */

.destymas {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="lt">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="Cloud architektai">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <title>Cloud architektai</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>        <!-- header start -->
            <div class="foreground-container">      <!-- foreground-container start -->
                <div class="nav-header">        <!-- nav-header start -->
                    <div class="background-container">      <!-- background-container start -->
                        <div class="slideshow-container">       <!-- slideshow-container start -->
                            <div class="fadein">       <!-- fadein start -->
                                <img src="images/bg-01.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
                                <img src="images/bg-02.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
                                <img src="images/bg-03.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
                                <img src="images/bg-04.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
                                <img src="images/bg-05.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
                                <br>        <!-- not required -->
                            </div>      <!-- fadein end -->
                        </div>      <!-- slideshow-container end -->
                    </div>      <!-- background-container end -->
                    <div class="nav-header-container container">        <!-- nav-header-container start -->
                        <div class="row row-eq-height">       <!-- row start -->
                            <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                                <a href="index.html"><img id="logo-bg" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" width="250" height="auto" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu-right col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
                                <ul id="menu">      <!-- menu start -->
                                    <li><a href="#">PROJEKTAI</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">PASLAUGOS</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">PROJEKTAVIMAS</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">TERITORIJŲ PLANAVIMAS</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">INTERJERO DIZAINAS</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">BIM</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">INDIVIDUALIOS KONSULTACIJOS</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">NAUJIENOS</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">APIE MUS</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">MISIJA IR VIZIJA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">KOMANDA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">STUDIJA</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">APDOVANOJIMAI</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">SPAUDA</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">KONTAKTAI</a></li>
                                </ul>       <!-- menu end -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear:both;"></div>
                        </div>      <!-- row end -->
                    </div>      <!-- nav-header-container end -->
                </div>      <!-- nav-header end -->
            </div>      <!-- foreground-container end -->
            <br>
        </header>       <!-- header end -->
        <main>
            <div class="destymas container">
                <img src="images/bg-02.jpg" style="width: 100%" />
                <h3>Text text text.</h3>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, you already did a good job at describing your problem, but to make it easier for other people to help you, you could try to improve your question, by reducing the code to the real minimum (remove all things which are not required to show the problem, e.g. only show x image instead of y), see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You have a z-index problem. Give the thing that's supposed to be on top a `position: relative; z-index: abignumbergoeshere`. That'll make sure it's always on top of everything else.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. But as I do an inspect and hover on background or slideshow container, it shows nothing. On the contrary, as I hover on navigation container. Seems that background and slideshow container does not fill any container space... Maybe its html structure things?